# Is $Spec(\Bbb R[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle)[ \frac{1}{ x−y} ]$ connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connectedness, idempotents, affine-schemes

I cannot see if $Spec(\Bbb R[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle)[ \frac{1}{ x−y} ]$ is connected.

I have tried to see if there exists some nontrivial idempotent in the ring $\Bbb R[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle)[ \frac{1}{ x−y} ]$ it seems not easy. I have just proved that we have no nontrivial idempotent in $\Bbb R[x,y]/\langle xy\rangle$ and I guess it may helps.

Any ideas of how to see if this affine scheme is connected?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I would suggest thinking about it geometrically instead of algebraically.

Comment: @EricWofsey Let me try geometrically from the definition of connectedness. I see it is disconnected. Let $I=\langle x\rangle, J=\langle y \rangle$ then $1=zx-zy\in I+J$ so $I+J=1$. And $IJ=\langle xy\rangle =\langle 0\rangle$ so $D_I \cup D_J=D_{I+J}=D_{\langle 1\rangle}=X,D_I\cap D_J=D_{\sqrt{IJ}}=D_{\sqrt{\langle 0\rangle}}=\emptyset$. May I  please ask if it is correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @PropositionX You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is disconnected. Let $I=⟨x⟩,J=⟨y⟩$ then $1=zx−zy∈I+J$ so $I+J=\langle 1\rangle$. And $IJ=⟨xy⟩=⟨0⟩$ so $D_I∪D_J=D_{I+J}=D_{⟨1⟩}=X$,$D_I∩D_J=D_{IJ}=D_{⟨0⟩}=∅$.

This proves that the scheme is disconnected.